# Run intellij scala formatter from the command line

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, formatting

I'm trying to add a git hook to format files automatically using IntelliJ formatter. It works well using https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/command-line-formatter.html but it doesn't work with scala files

```
Formatting /Users/me/IdeaProjects/repo/MyFile.scala...Skipped, not supported.
```

I usually use the git client in intellij and I check `Reformat code` but I'm trying to find a solution that is agnostic of the git client. Is there a way to use intellij scala formatter from the command line?

Comment: As a side note, if you could be interested, IntelliJ recently started supporting `scalafmt` natively, which ships by default with a CLI: https://github.com/scalameta/scalafmt

Comment: Use scalafmt instead, it works much better than IntelliJ's convntions.

Comment: Seems to work on my machine by executing `idea format foo.scala`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to be git-client agnostic you should also be IDE agnostic - code formatting can be done using `scalafmt` from [command line](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#cli) (which allows using [git-hook](https://github.com/coyainsurance/pre-commit-scalafmt)) or by [build tool like sbt](https://github.com/scalameta/sbt-scalafmt) to format/check that files are formatted. IntelliJ [is also supported](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/installation.html#intellij).

You can still try to use IntelliJ formatter but this will NOT work for anyone who doesn't have IntelliJ installed. In such case they would have to disable git hook which defeats the purpose. As you noticed it is also difficult to make it work - in your example I guess this might be some config issue, like the need to generate IntelliJ project first, having Scala plugin installed, and run command exactly from the root of the project. Even if that will be enough to make things work, it would already be enough to decide against using IDE specific tools in the workflow.

Comment: Thank you, I hoped I could use the same file Project.xml for code style settings but it doesn't seem possible and scalafmt looks a better option